# How to enter the data of thousands person in vector?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi i am novice in java and i am adding the objects in vector right now i am adding two objects  but if i want to enter the data of thousand person through a file or from a database how can i do it right now i have three class. and the code as follow:-

```
public class Customer {

    private int custid;
    private String custname;
    private float custsalary;

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("Customer Id     :=" + custid+"\n");
        buffer.append("Customer Name   :=" + custname+"\n");
        buffer.append("Customer Salary :=" + custsalary+"\n");
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public int getCustid() {
        return custid;
    }

    public void setCustid(int custid) {
        this.custid = custid;
    }

    public String getCustname() {
        return custname;
    }

    public void setCustname(String custname) {
        this.custname = custname;
    }

    public float getCustsalary() {
        return custsalary;
    }

    public void setCustsalary(float custsalary) {
        this.custsalary = custsalary;
    }

}
```

and second class is

```
package com.test.collection.list.vector.custom;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CustomerVector {

    public void custDetails(){

        Customer c1Obj = new Customer();
        c1Obj.setCustid(123);
        c1Obj.setCustname("Kb");
        c1Obj.setCustsalary(1000.34f);

        Customer c2Obj = new Customer();
        c2Obj.setCustid(456);
        c2Obj.setCustname("nv");
        c2Obj.setCustsalary(2000.34f);

        Vector<Customer> v = new Vector<Customer>();
        v.addElement(c1Obj);
        v.addElement(c2Obj);

        Enumeration<Customer> custEnum = v.elements();
        while (custEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            Customer customer = custEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my client code

```
package com.test.collection.list.vector.custom;

public class ClientCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerVector custVectObj = new CustomerVector();
        custVectObj.custDetails();
    }
}
```

My question is if i want to add the data of thousand person what will be the easiest and effective approach for it

Comment: To start with, you usually don't want `Vector`; it's synchronized and therefore slow. Consider using a `List` instead.

Comment: yes i know but the concept will be the same in vector as well as in List. my main motive is how to add the multiple persons data by a loop or whatever. because according to this approach i have to make the object thousand time for thousand person.

Comment: you may face performance issue if you load 1000's of records at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CustomVector with this:

```
public class CustomerVector {

    Vector<Customer> v = null;

    public CustomVector(){
        v = new Vector<Customer>();
    }

    public void createCustomer(int id, String name, float salary){
        Customer c1Obj = new Customer();
        c1Obj.setCustid(id);
        c1Obj.setCustname(name);
        c1Obj.setCustsalary(salary);

        v.addElement(c1Obj);
    }
    public void custDetails(){

        Enumeration<Customer> custEnum = v.elements();
        while (custEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            Customer customer = custEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

and in your main, add vectors

```
package com.test.collection.list.vector.custom;

public class ClientCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerVector custVectObj = new CustomerVector();
        // Add Customers
        custVectObj.createCustomer(1,"joan",10.03f);
        custVectObj.custDetails();
    }
}
```

Automatic main method that generates 1000 different elements:

```
package com.test.collection.list.vector.custom;

public class ClientCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerVector custVectObj = new CustomerVector();
        // Add Customers
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            custVectObj.createCustomer(i,"name"+i,i);
        }
        custVectObj.custDetails();
    }
}
```

You can use instead `Random class` to make the test suite a bit more different.

Comment: But the same thing i am doing in my code.. by using your code if i have to display the data of 1000 customer then i have to call this method thousand time. is it possible to do it in loop ??

Comment: ofc it is possible, just add a loop that contains `custVectObj.createCustomer(1,"joan",10.03f);` line, inside the loop you can call for input the information

Comment: and please explain why you are passing the vector object in constructor of 'CustomVector' what is the benefit of it ?? or you are doing association ??

Comment: You have to initialize it in the constructor in order to add elements to the same vector on createCustomer method, I think you bypass some java basis before doing that homework :P

Comment: But how ca i generate the values of name customer id etc. dynamically because it will get change every time for each customer

Comment: If you need to dynamically create 1000 objects I would use random numbers, i will edit the answer to show you how

Comment: yes you are correct not that much clear in basics but i was asking cz we can also did it by creating it in start of create Customer  method.

Comment: Check the modification I did to show you how to generate 1000 different elements